# How to find Curved Grade in Google Sheets?

Tags: arrays, if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I'm working on a file where final grades of all courses are added, every student has the right to get up to 5 grades as curve for all of his/her final grades with are lower than **Passing Grade**. My question is: is it possible to find new **final grades** with added grades by a **Formula** and/or **Script** in Google Sheets.
Below is a sample of the data

```
studentName         course          final           final (withCurve)
A                    Math             59              60
A                    Physics          58              60
A                    English          54              54
B                    English          55              55
B                    Physics          58              60
B                    French           57              60
```

**Note**: Assume the passing Grade is **60** and give the 5 grades to more courses as possible, which means better to give it to 57, 58 than one single 55 **(if it is possible)**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as requested the passing point is **60** and awarder are only **5** bonus points only to students that fail in particular subjects and those bonus points are distributed to cap up the passing value

so, the formula would be:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A3:A&B3:B, QUERY(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(
 QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE("♦"&QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY({
 SORT(FILTER(A3:C, C3:C<60, C3:C>54), 1, 1, 3, 1), 
 SORT(FILTER(ROW(A3:A), C3:C<60, C3:C>54), 1, 0)}, 
 "select max(Col3) where Col1 is not null group by Col4 pivot Col1")), "select Col1", 0)&
 QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(QUERY({SORT(FILTER(A3:C, C3:C<60, C3:C>54), 1, 1, 3, 1), 
 SORT(FILTER(ROW(A3:A), C3:C<60, C3:C>54), 1, 0)}, 
 "select Col2,max(Col3) where Col1 is not null group by Col4,Col2 pivot Col1"), 
 "offset 1", 0)), "limit 0", 1)&"♠"&
 IFNA(REGEXREPLACE(TO_TEXT(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(QUERY({SORT(FILTER(A3:C, C3:C<60, C3:C>54), 1, 1, 3, 1), 
 SORT(FILTER(ROW(A3:A), C3:C<60, C3:C>54), 1, 0)}, 
 "select max(Col3) where Col1 is not null group by Col4 pivot Col1"), "offset 1", 0))), "^60$", )+IFNA(
 IF(IFERROR(QUERY(1*REGEXREPLACE(TO_TEXT(60-TRANSPOSE(QUERY(QUERY({SORT(FILTER(A3:C, C3:C<60, C3:C>54), 1, 1, 3, 1),
 SORT(FILTER(ROW(A3:A), C3:C<60, C3:C>54), 1, 0)}, 
 "select max(Col3) where Col1 is not null group by Col4 pivot Col1"), "offset 1", 0))), "^60$", ), 
 "select Col1+Col2+Col3+Col4+Col5 label Col1+Col2+Col3+Col4+Col5''"), 6)<=5, 
 REGEXREPLACE(TO_TEXT(60-TRANSPOSE(QUERY(QUERY({SORT(FILTER(A3:C, C3:C<60, C3:C>54), 1, 1, 3, 1), 
 SORT(FILTER(ROW(A3:A), C3:C<60, C3:C>54), 1, 0)}, 
 "select max(Col3) where Col1 is not null group by Col4 pivot Col1"), "offset 1", 0))), "^60$", ),
 IF(IFERROR(QUERY(1*REGEXREPLACE(TO_TEXT(60-TRANSPOSE(QUERY(QUERY({SORT(FILTER(A3:C, C3:C<60, C3:C>54), 1, 1, 3, 1),
 SORT(FILTER(ROW(A3:A), C3:C<60, C3:C>54), 1, 0)}, 
 "select max(Col3) where Col1 is not null group by Col4 pivot Col1"), "offset 1", 0))), "^60$", ), 
 "select Col1+Col2+Col3+Col4 label Col1+Col2+Col3+Col4''"), 6)<=5, 
 REGEXREPLACE(TO_TEXT(60-TRANSPOSE(QUERY(QUERY({SORT(FILTER(A3:C, C3:C<60, C3:C>54), 1, 1, 3, 1), 
 SORT(FILTER(ROW(A3:A), C3:C<60, C3:C>54), 1, 0)}, 
 "select max(Col3) where Col1 is not null group by Col4 pivot Col1"), "offset 1", 0))), "^60$", ), 
 IF(IFERROR(QUERY(1*REGEXREPLACE(TO_TEXT(60-TRANSPOSE(QUERY(QUERY({SORT(FILTER(A3:C, C3:C<60, C3:C>54), 1, 1, 3, 1),
 SORT(FILTER(ROW(A3:A), C3:C<60, C3:C>54), 1, 0)}, 
 "select max(Col3) where Col1 is not null group by Col4 pivot Col1"), "offset 1", 0))), "^60$", ), 
 "select Col1+Col2+Col3 label Col1+Col2+Col3''"), 6)<=5, QUERY(
 REGEXREPLACE(TO_TEXT(60-TRANSPOSE(QUERY(QUERY({SORT(FILTER(A3:C, C3:C<60, C3:C>54), 1, 1, 3, 1),
 SORT(FILTER(ROW(A3:A), C3:C<60, C3:C>54), 1, 0)}, 
 "select max(Col3) where Col1 is not null group by Col4 pivot Col1"), "offset 1", 0))), "^60$", ), 
 "select Col1,Col2,Col3"),
 IF(IFERROR(QUERY(1*REGEXREPLACE(TO_TEXT(60-TRANSPOSE(QUERY(QUERY({SORT(FILTER(A3:C, C3:C<60, C3:C>54), 1, 1, 3, 1),
 SORT(FILTER(ROW(A3:A), C3:C<60, C3:C>54), 1, 0)}, 
 "select max(Col3) where Col1 is not null group by Col4 pivot Col1"), "offset 1", 0))), "^60$", ), 
 "select Col1+Col2 label Col1+Col2''"), 6)<=5, QUERY(
 REGEXREPLACE(TO_TEXT(60-TRANSPOSE(QUERY(QUERY({SORT(FILTER(A3:C, C3:C<60, C3:C>54), 1, 1, 3, 1),
 SORT(FILTER(ROW(A3:A), C3:C<60, C3:C>54), 1, 0)}, 
 "select max(Col3) where Col1 is not null group by Col4 pivot Col1"), "offset 1", 0))), "^60$", ),
 "select Col1,Col2"), 
 IF(IFERROR(QUERY(1*REGEXREPLACE(TO_TEXT(60-TRANSPOSE(QUERY(QUERY({SORT(FILTER(A3:C, C3:C<60, C3:C>54), 1, 1, 3, 1), 
 SORT(FILTER(ROW(A3:A), C3:C<60, C3:C>54), 1, 0)}, 
 "select max(Col3) where Col1 is not null group by Col4 pivot Col1"), "offset 1", 0))), "^60$", ), 
 "select Col1 "),6)<=5, QUERY(
 REGEXREPLACE(TO_TEXT(60-TRANSPOSE(QUERY(QUERY({SORT(FILTER(A3:C, C3:C<60, C3:C>54), 1, 1, 3, 1),
 SORT(FILTER(ROW(A3:A), C3:C<60, C3:C>54), 1, 0)}, 
 "select max(Col3) where Col1 is not null group by Col4 pivot Col1"), "offset 1", 0))), "^60$", ) ,
 "select Col1"), ))))), 0), 0)),,999^99)),,999^99), "♦")), "♠"), "where Col2 !=0"), 2, 0), C3:C))
```

[image: 0]

### [spreadsheet demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yPHzszXH0G3FuppooQQOnvrd6PY-ya1JCckdoF6vE8Y/copy)

Comment: It was just great, could you help one more thing. How to make it like this: if a student can not be passed with the remaining bounce, he/she must not receive it. for example, a student has 57 and 56, **3** to be added to **57** and since he can pass with **2**, therefore, the **56** must remain as the same.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF((C2:C>56)*(C2:C<60), 60, C2:C))
```

[image: 0]

---

## UPDATE:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(A3:A&" "&B3:B, {TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(SORT({A3:C}, 1, 1, 3, 0),999^99, 2)),,999^99)), IF(
 MMULT(--TRANSPOSE(IF((TRANSPOSE(ROW(A3:A))>=ROW(A3:A))*(A3:A=TRANSPOSE(A3:A)), 
 60-INDEX(SORT({A3:A, IF((C3:C<60)*(C3:C>54), C3:C, 0)}, 1, 1, 2, 0),,2), 0)), 
 ROW(A3:A)^0)<=5, 
 60-INDEX(SORT({A3:A, IF((C3:C<60)*(C3:C>54), C3:C, 0)}, 1, 1, 2, 0),,2)+
 INDEX(SORT({A3:A, IF((C3:C<60)*(C3:C>54), C3:C, 0)}, 1, 1, 2, 0),,2), 
 INDEX(SORT({A3:A, C3:C}, 1, 1, 2, 0),,2))}, 2, 0))
```

[image: 0]

### [spreadsheet demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10sHtJoMRbzOaxdJbx0oAvs6qkjCtKJgaRtYOCshLO38/copy)

Comment: Thanks, there is a problem, every student can have up to 5 grades, NOT every grades between 55 and 59 to be changed to 60. How to solve this?

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet or some mockup with data structure and example of desired output?

Comment: please find a sheet with sample data below [click HERE to open](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1f033YmhbwZgB-iaWsFj6W3eQ9dDo8Qbz3fp9kFRTpV4/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: is 60 the max value?

Comment: I see, well then there is just one issue... the distribution of those 5 bonus points... there are two options I can think of: 1: distribute them evenly to top 5 highest values ber person or 2: target the max value threshold (eg. 100) and try to max out top capacity and then move to the 2nd highest and max it, then 3rd etc.... so which logic you want to follow?

Comment: I think it must be a mixture between those options that you mentioned, because those 5 bounce points will be given to those students who have failed, not to everyone.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201578/discussion-between-aree-ali-and-player0).